# Hibernate query involving a @ManyToOne relationship

Tags: hibernate

I have a class declared as

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "word", schema = "public")
public class Word implements java.io.Serializable {
    ...
    private ContentLanguage contentLanguage;
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "content_language_id", nullable = false)
    public ContentLanguageT getContentLanguage() {
        return this.contentLanguage;
    }

    public void setContentLanguage(ContentLanguage contentLanguage) {
        this.contentLanguage = contentLanguage;
    }
  ...
```

ContentLanguage is declared as

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "content_language", schema = "public")
    public class ContentLanguage implements java.io.Serializable {

        private int id;
        private String value;
 ....
```

My action needs to query for all Words who's ContentLanguage field has an id = 1
I thought I might be able to create a criteria against ContentLanguage class and then add this to a Criteria against the Word table but obviously this is not the way to do it.
Any ideas as I don't want to have to go and start using SQL or HQL for what is a relatively simple task?

```
                public String execute() 
    {       
        //DetachedCriteria criteria1 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ContentLanguageT.class);
        //criteria1.add(Restrictions.eq("id",1));
        DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(WordT.class);
        //criteria.add( criteria1 );
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("contentLanguageT", Integer.valueOf( contentLangID )));        
        allWords = wordDao.findByCriteria( criteria, 0, 50);        
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Word.contentLanguage` is of type `ContentLanguage`. SO you can't compare it with an integer. You may only compare it with a ContentLanguage. So, either you do

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("contentLanguage.id", contentLanguageId));
```

or you do

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("contentLanguage", 
                             session.load(ContentLanguage.class, contentLanguageId)));
```

I really prefer HQL for such simple static queries. Isn't the following much more readable and intuitive?

```
select w from Word w 
where w.contentLanguage.id = :contentLanguageId
```

Comment: Cheers mate,  I understood that I couldn't compare ContentLanguage with an Integer but I couldn't figure out how to access the ID field within the ContentLanguage object.  Your answer was what I was hoping for.  Our tech guy here wants us to use Criteria where ever possible so the HQL option will not fly with him ( Don't ask me why :( )  Thanks again